# Angular 14 - The property and event halves of the two-way binding 'value' are not bound to the same target

Tags: angular, typescript

Migrated from Angular 10.1 to 14. And got a lot of errors most of them related to types, which I could resolve. Need help to resolve the one below about two way binding.

`[(value)]="e.descr"`  (see the below component.html)

**Error**: In the below error message, the component.ts line numbers referred to have no relation(seemingly) to the part in component.html where error occured.

```
The property and event halves of the two-way binding 'value' are not bound to the same target.
            Find more at https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-worksngtsc(-998007)
index.d.ts(48, 30): The property half of the binding is to the 'MatInput' component.
mca-edit-invoice.ts(237, 24): The event half of the binding is to a native event called 'value' on the <textarea> DOM element.

Are you missing an output declaration called 'valueChange'?
mca-edit-invoice.ts(48, 12): Error occurs in the template of component McaEditInvoiceComponent.
```

**component.html**

```
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="addedItemDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
               .....
              <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let e, let i = index"  formArrayName="descr" style='width: 60%'>
                  {{e.name}}
                  <br>
                  <div *ngIf="e.rate !== null">
                    <mat-form-field style="width: 98%;">
                                                              //// ERROR for BELOW
                      <textarea matInput [formControlName]='i' [(value)]="e.descr"  
                      rows='3'>
                      </textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
```

**component.ts**

```
    addedItemDataSource!: MatTableDataSource<AddedInvoiceItem>;


    this.cForm = this.fb.group({
      clientName: [{value:'', disabled: false}, Validators.required],
      clientLocn: {value:'', disabled: false},
      retMth:'',
      retYr: '',
      rate: new FormArray([]),
      descr: new FormArray([]),
      invDate: ['', Validators.required],
      bankName: ['', Validators.required],
      remarks: '',
    })
```

Comment: **NEVER** use [value] nor [(value)] nor [checked] in an input that use a FormControl.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute does not support two way binding. Use `ngModel` instead.

```html
<textarea [(ngModel)]="e.descr" ... >
```

This requires the `FormsModule` to be imported.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqscfa?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I have used ReactiveFormsModule. Can I resolve this error using Reactive Forms options?

Comment: @hemant Sure, just erase `[(value)]="e.descr"` - that has nothing to do with reactive forms. `formControlName` is what binds the value to a form control. `[(value)]="e.descr"` is for a template driven form.